# Are these maps homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X=Y=S^1$ and $p_1: X \rightarrow Y$,$p_2: X \rightarrow Y$ functions $p_1(z)=z^n$,$p_1(z)=z^m$ for fixed $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$. Are $p_1$ and $p_2$ homotopic maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us first prove the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** Let $p_1,p_2\colon\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ be two continuous maps such that $\|p_1-p_2\|_{\infty}<2$, then $p_1$ and $p_2$ have the same degree.

**Proof.** Let $\theta_1,\theta_2\colon[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous maps such that: $$\forall t\in[0,1],p_1(e^{it})=e^{i\theta_1(t)},p_2(e^{it})=e^{i\theta_2(t)}.$$
The hypothesis on $\|p_1-p_2\|_{\infty}$ allows us to choose $\theta_1,\theta_2$ such that: $$|\theta_1(0)-\theta_2(0)|<\pi.$$
Using the intermediate value theorem, one must have: $$|\theta_1(2\pi)-\theta_2(2\pi)|<\pi.$$
Otherwise, one would have a point $t_0\in[0,1]$ such that $|\theta_1(t_0)-\theta_2(t_0)|=\pi$ and $|p_1(e^{it_0})-p_2(e^{it_0})|=2$ which is excluded! Therefore, one has: $$|\deg(p_1)-\deg(p_2)|=\left|\frac{\theta_1(2\pi)-\theta_1(0)}{2\pi}-\frac{\theta_2(2\pi)-\theta_2(0)}{2\pi}\right|<1.$$ Whence the result since the degree is an integer. $\Box$

From there one derives the following proposition:

> **Proposition.** Let $p_1,p_2\colon\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ be two continuous maps. If $p_1$ and $p_2$ are homotopic, then $p_1$ and $p_2$ have the same degree.

**Proof.** Let $H:[0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ be a continuous homotopy between $p_1$ and $p_2$, since $[0,1]$ is compact, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}_{\geqslant 1}$ such that: $$\forall j\in\{0,\cdots,N-1\},\left\|H\left(\frac{j}{N},\cdot\right)-H\left(\frac{j+1}{N},\cdot\right)\right\|_{\infty}<2.$$
Using the lemma, for all $j\in\{0,\cdots,N-1\}$, $\displaystyle H\left(\frac{j}{N},\cdot\right)$ and $\displaystyle H\left(\frac{j}{N},\cdot\right)$ have the same degree. Whence the result, since $H(0,\cdot)=p_1$ and $H(1,\cdot)=p_2$. $\Box$

Therefore, $p_1$ and $p_2$ are homotopic if and only if $n=m$.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the downvote!

Comment: I just don't understand this downvote, your answer is perfectly written and you did put lot of details ... I upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Under the covering map $\eta:\mathbb{R} \to S^1; t \mapsto e^{2\pi it}$, we have that $p_1$ lifts to a path from $0$ to $n$ on $\mathbb{R}$  and $p_2$ lifts to a path from $0$ to $m$. Therefore, if $n \neq m$, they can't be homotopic. If $n=m$, they are trivially homotopic.